# Flaky alarm system

Tags: alarm, security

My wife's Acura's alarm system was the most sensitive one I had ever run across. It was installed by the former owner, a professor in Princeton. Now we are in a little town with low crime so when the alarm system died, we danced on it's grave. Now it has returned like a shambling zombie, occasionally beeping and going off randomly (once while driving). That won't do. Is there anyway I can disable the alarm without just clipping the wires? The functions that prevent the car from starting haven't re-surfaced, just the alarm

**UPDATE**
Well it is a third party alarm, unfortunately I cant find where it connects to the battery. I tried following some wires off the shock sensors but it enters into a rather full wire wrap. I also cant find any way of identifying the make and model of the alarm.

**UPDATE 2**
Well, good I guess. It got better. I still cant figure out why but it runs fine now. I won't delete this in case any answers current or future help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself. I can't figure out why or how. The only idea I have is either the battery was starting to drop (unlikely as there was no problem cranking) or there was a capacitor starting to fail.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a third-party alarm, you can probably just disconnect it from the battery. There should be a thinner red wire running from either the positive battery terminal or a positive auxiliary connection possibly near the battery.

If the alarm also came with remote-start, we'll have to discuss a different solution. Depending on the system you might need it un-wired completely if you need to go back to using the factory FOB for locking/unlocking doors (if you had one).

Comment: Thank you for giving me a place to start looking. I have been staring at the fuses for awhile but could never figure out the right one.